# React Native Firebase Auth user is null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have integrated the @react-native-firebase/auth package for user authentication. On the 'onAuthStateChanged' listener the user object is null without calling the signout. Are there any possible fixes for this?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same issue. But in React application 
It's happened because u need to wait, before firebase-auth get authenticated user. So, you can create useState with default loading in true position. And while it's loading - display spinner or something else. When user will be load - setLoading to false with useEffect.

My app.js:

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (authorizedUser) => {
    if (authorizedUser) {
      console.log('success sign-in')
      setUser(authorizedUser);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: How do we add the logic to wait in the above code

Comment: See full example here - https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage

Comment: We followed the same documentation. But somehow the user value is null in 'onAuthStateChanged' handler.

Comment: Maybe you have connection firebase problem? Can u create a codesandox or something to show your code?